# Ansible complex nested loop example

Tags: ansible

Assume I have three lists of the following format.

```
   ['A', 'B']
   ['1', '2']
   ['a','b','c','d']
```

I need to get to the following output:

```
A1a
A2a
A1b
A2b
B1c
B2c
B1d
B2d
```

Notice it is not a simple one-to-one with nested as that would be 16 output lines.  In this example I only want 8. In the output, I can't have the second column with any duplicates in the third column.  "A1a and B1a" would be a bad combination.

I have tried many combinations of with_nested and with_flattened and can't seem to get where I need to be.

My next approach is to create a dict with all of them and see about iterating over that somehow.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is `with_cartesian`

Here is the example code:

```
- debug: 
    msg: "{{item | join ()}}"
  with_cartesian:
    - ['A', 'B']
    - ['1', '2']
    - ['a','b','c','d']
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this doesn't quite work.  This will output 16 and is similar to with_nested output.  It violates the rule: "I can't have the second column with any duplicates in the third column. "A1a and B1a" would be a bad combination".